# Croppie js result returns blank images

Tags: javascript, jquery, croppie

people I am working with `croppie` js where I need to crop an image in circle all this will be done on a modal which will be shown as the file input changes, and save it to database. Currently I only need to display the crop image ie., the result of `croppie` image but as I click on save to display my cropped image I'm getting blank white image in response. I tried to figure out the issue and appears to me like I'm binding `croppie` instance before showing my modal but I'm quite sure that's not the case here. I'm not getting anything like warning error on console too. Wonder what is going fishy with my code.

here is my code along with [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bkcamtr4/1/)

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" class="form-control file-input" id="studentAvatar">

<!-- modal -->


    <div class="modal fade" id="cropper" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div id="preview">
                        <img src="#" class="previewImg">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="save">Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
$image_crop = $('#preview').croppie({
            enableExif: true,
            viewport: {
                width: 150,
                height: 150,
                type: 'circle'
            },
            boundary: {
                width: 300,
                height: 300
            }
        });
        function readURL(input) {

            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function(e) {
                    $image_crop.croppie('bind', {
                        url: e.target.result
                    }).then(function(){
                        $('#previewImg').attr('src', e.target.result);
                        console.log('jQuery bind complete');
                    });
                    $(".save").on('click',function (e) {
                        $image_crop.croppie('result',{
                            type:'base64',
                            size:'original',
                            circle:true
                        }).then(function (response) {
                            console.log(response);
                            $(".previewImg").attr('src', response)
                        });
                    })
                }

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }
        $("#studentAvatar").change(function(){
            $("#cropper").modal('show');
            console.log(this);
            readURL(this);
        });
```

Thanks for help :)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `$("#cropper").modal('show');` for `$("#cropper").modal('shown.bs.modal');`

With this you will be sure that de modal is completly loaded before than `readURL()`

Answer (score 0):

Your modal initialization code should be like below because `readURL()` function should be initialized after the modal is completely shown

```
$("#studentAvatar").change(function(){
    $("#cropper").modal();
});

$("#cropper").on("shown.bs.modal", function () {
   // after modal being completely opened, fire the readURL() function
   readURL(this);
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with you, please check this link.

[the desired link](https://codepen.io/thedustinsmith/pen/KEEBKX)

HTML:

```
<div id="demo-basic"></div>
<img id="imgbase64" />
<button id="dostuff">do stuff</button>
```

JS:

```
var el = document.getElementById('demo-basic');
    var vanilla = new Croppie(el, {
        viewport: { width: 100, height: 100 },
        boundary: { width: 300, height: 300 },
        showZoomer: false,
        enableOrientation: true,
        enableResize: true,
        mouseWheelZoom: 'ctrl'
    });
    vanilla.bind({
        url: 'http://placekitten.com/g/200/300',
        orientation: 4
    });

    document.getElementById('dostuff').addEventListener('click', function (ev) {

        vanilla.result({ type: "base64", format: "jpeg", size: 'original' }).then(function (base64) {
            document.getElementById("imgbase64").setAttribute("src", base64);
        });
    });
```